# How can I add some data to the end of my text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="rep_tb0" >
    <div class="rep_tr0" >
        <div class="rep_td0"  id="ActivityLog">Activity Log</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I a trying to use the following to add the data:

```
$("#ActivityLog").append("text example ").append("<br />");
```

But it doesn't seem to add data after the text "Activity Log". Am I doing the jQuery correctly? Note that I do need two appends as the information where I have put "text example" will be from a data query later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping in the `ready` function:

```
$(function(){

    $("#ActivityLog").append("text example ").append("<br />");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#ActivityLog').append('text example ').end().append('<br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ActivityLog").html($("#ActivityLog").html() + "text example ");
```